# NativeScript Project Build Successfully. but nothing happen

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to run

**$tns run android --emulator**

Apps build successfully but nothing happen.

```
:config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles

:config phase:  copyAarDependencies

:config phase:  addAarDependencies
        +adding dependency: C:\1Projects\NS Web\workstation\ns-mobile\platforms\
android\libs\aar\widgets-release.aar
:deleteMetadata
:deleteFlavors
:clean UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 23.072 secs
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:552:26)
```

Comment: This error itself is not enough to diagnose your issue.. pllease provide the sample code that is causing this ibehaviour or/and run your command like "tns run android --emulator --log trace " to generate a more detailed error log

Comment: The issue has been resolved after updating npm and nativescript.